# Sharing folders in NTFS partitions in a network with SMB

Tags: networking, permissions, samba, shared-folders, smb

I have a computer on my office with Ubuntu 14.04 and a laptop with the same configuration. I would like to share a folder I have in the office computer inside the network.

I went to this folder and clicked on "Sharing options", checking both "Share this folder" and "Guest access" (because i figured it would just make it simpler).

In my laptop, I click on Network and then in MERCURY (The name of my Office computer) and I see the folder "movies". But when I try to open it, I get an error: "Unable to mount Window Share: Permission Denied".

What have I missed?

**UPDATE:** My folder is in a NTFS partition. Is that a problem?

Comment: Check the folder permissions. They must be set to give access to anyone.

Comment: Sorry, it is a NTFS partition :P

Comment: Maybe... Sorry,I've no FAT partition had hand to test... Ninjaded... :-) It's NTFS... Honestly, I don't know. NTFS users and groups are not the same, and I wouldn't be confident with using chmod to modify them.

Answer (score 1):

There could be several reasons that it's not working, but rather than troubleshoot the "simpler" method, it would probably be much easier (and much more secure) to share it only with yourself, unless you need to share it with others, in which case they would need a login on the system, and the folder would need to allow access by them.

If you only share it with known users, then you will need to give the user name and password the first time, but it should remember in the future (assuming you tell it to).  I don't actually use Windows, but I'm assuming it works the same as Ubuntu, more or less (I hope, anyway).

Comment: But that is not really a solution to my problem... And I never mentioned Windows at all...

Comment: @Dbugger - Well, excuse me for trying to help; my method has worked for me on a number of occasions.  I guess I thought your problem was connecting to the desktop, not making a bad solution work.  And I never said it was a Windows-only solution, but your error did mention Windows, and you now say you have an NTFS partition, which is not used with Linux by most people who know better.  Good luck with your problem, whatever it is.